# image uploaded with Carrierwave not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm having an issue with Carrierwave (0.10.0) that's driving me nuts.
For some reason, beyond my understanding, images uploaded with Carrierwave, result in a 404 error in the browser.

However when I check the path, it's correct.

the configuration for the storage directory is like this:

```
app/uploaders/screenshot_uploader.rb
...
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
...
```

in my view template I show the image like this:

```
/app/views/projects/show.html.erb
...
<%= image_tag @project.screenshot_url if @project.screenshot? %>
```

in the browser I get this error:

```
GET http://projecttracker.ugent.be:3000/uploads/project/screenshot/3/afp2013.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

If I go look in that folder, the file is there.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on?

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: Assuming that you can reach other pages in your site in development mode (deducing from the use of :3000 port), it's hard to imagine something other than some typo in url causing this kind of error.